# How order items based on votes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to render a list of the top 10 photos ordered by their votes this is how I decided to do it:

```
@top_photos = Photo.all(:joins => :votes, :select => "photos.*, count(*) as vote_total",:group => "votes.photo_id", :order => "vote_total DESC" )#, :limit => 10)
```

but i am getting the following error from my heroku logs:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column "photos.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Works find on localhost with sqlite but does not work at all with postgres on heroku. Looking for some insight on what this may be or just an alternative way to achieve the same thing.
Cheers

Comment: This is some kind of postgres limitation, try grouping by `photos.id`

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel it's not "postgres limitation", it's strict aproach to queries.

Comment: @JakubKania call it as you wish ;)

Comment: Lol well whatever it's called changing to group by photos.id worked perfectly. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Most databases don't allow to select non-aggregated columns which are not included in `GROUP BY` statement, SQLite and MySQL. It's not really a place to talk about which one is better but the short answer is: Include every non-aggregated column in the group by clause (every column in photos table basicaly). You will also want to stop using * as this will break your query if a new column is added.

Comment: Mostly right, though the SQL standard does require that if the `PRIMARY KEY` is in `GROUP BY` then all other columns of the table must be considered explicitly grouped.

Comment: @CraigRinger that is correct but still no db I know really checks that, they just either allow query in that form or they don't regardless if it's valid or not.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.1 and newer detect functional dependencies of the `PRIMARY KEY`. I though that was a common feature of higher end RDBMSes, too, but haven't verified.

Comment: @CraigRinger Wow, I didn't know that. Cool. So according to my best knowledge PG supports that, MSSQL doesn't and MySQL and SQLite don't check if it's valid